# Python : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Tags: python, pandas, pip, pycharm

I got this err:
import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

My versions installed are:
Python ver  3.9.7
pandas  1.3.3
pip 21.2.4
PyCharm 11.0.12

I can see pandas installed in pycharm, but when I am importing it I got that err.
Any clue?
Thank you

Comment: Could you share some screenshots of the error, as well as the packages installed and the environment you are using?

Comment: pip3 install pandas

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall pandas package.

type = pip install pandas

wait for some time and then your panda package will get installed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution, and it worked:

The fix is simple: Use the PyCharm installation tooltips to install Pandas in your virtual environment—two clicks and you’re good to go!

First, right-click on the pandas text in your editor:

Second, click “Show Context Actions” in your context menu. In the new menu that arises, click “Install Pandas” and wait for PyCharm to finish the installation.

Source:
https://blog.finxter.com/how-to-fix-importerror-no-module-named-pandas/